# How to add multiple "Forwarding routes" to stock VPN client?

Tags: vpn

I am in need of adding two specific routes to the "Forwarding routes" section of the stock VPN client.  How can I accomplish that?

Lets say I need to add `1.0.0.0/24` & `255.0.0.0/24`. I have tried adding them every way I can think of and I am unable to save as soon as I try to add the second route.
EG:

```
1.0.0.0/24
255.0.0.0/24
1.0.0.0/24 255.0.0.0/24
1.0.0.0/24,255.0.0.0/24
1.0.0.0/24:255.0.0.0/24
1.0.0.0/24;255.0.0.0/24
1.0.0.0/24255.0.0.0/24
1.0.0.0/24&255.0.0.0/24
1.0.0.0/24 & 255.0.0.0/24
```

None of these options worked.

I know that I can use `0.0.0.0/0` but I don't want ALL of my traffic to go via the VPN as the VPN doesn't provide internet connectivity & is just used to gain access to specific equipment.

If this is not possible with the stock app, is there any other solution?

Comment: I swear I tried it with a space a few times & it didn't work.  It's working now though.  =/

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about PPTP / L2TP / IPSec VPN configuration in Settings:

[image]

I haven't used that, but according to [this source](https://getflix.zendesk.com/hc/en-gb/articles/204087170-DNS-over-VPN-Android-Devices) a space between routes should work:

> *"In the Forwarding routes box, enter X.X.X.X/X - optionally, you can also enter Y.Y.Y.Y/Y Z.Z.Z.Z/Z (put a space between each entry)."*

So this should work:

```
1.0.0.0/24 255.0.0.0/24
```

If it doesn't, I'm afraid rooting is the only way. Then you can modify routing policy (`ip rule show`) and kernel routing table (`ip route show table all`) as per your requirements.